# Rendering a CollectionView

Tags: backbone.js

This question has been asked at length yet I can't seem to get any of the examples to fit my code. My model and collection populate and I get output from the console, but can;t seem to get the AppView.render to do anything other then print 'rendering view...'

```
var Foodtruck = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    'name': '',
    'twitter': '',
    'categories': [],
    'coordinates': {
      'latitude': 0,
      'longitude': 0
    }
  }
});

var FoodTruckCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Foodtruck,
  url: 'http://api.mobilefeast.info/foodtrucks',
  initialize: function(){
        this.bind("render", function( model ){
            alert("hey");
            view.render( model );
        })
  },
  parse: function(response) {
    return response;
  },
  getData: function(){
    var that = this;
    that.fetch(
    {
        success: function () {
          console.log('Data is fetched');
        },
        error: function() {
          console.log('Failed to fetch!');
        }
   });
  }
});

var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:$('#container'),

    initialize: function(){
        console.log('initialize AppView');
        this.foodtrucks = new FoodTruckCollection();
        this.foodtrucks.getData();
    },
    render: function(){
        console.log('rendering view...');
        this.foodtrucks.each(function(model){
          console.log(JSON.stringify(model));
        });
    }
});

new AppView().render();
```

tried this question: [fetch after render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220092/backbone-js-view-renders-before-model-fetch)

but no luck

**Update**

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:$('#container'),
    initialize: function(){
        console.log('Initialize');
        this.foodtrucks = new FoodTruckCollection();
        this.foodtrucks.fetch(
        {
          success: function () {
            console.log('Data is fetched');
          },
          error: function() {
            console.log('Failed to fetch!');
          }
        });
        this.listenTo(this.foodtrucks, 'sync', this.render);
    },
    render: function(){
      console.log('Rendering');
      this.foodtrucks.each(function(model){
        console.log(model.toJSON().name);
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: try add this to `AppView initialize`: `this.listenTo(this.foodtrucks, 'sync', this.render);`

Usually you might want to listen to `add` or `change` instead but for your case 'sync' should be fine, I think.

Comment: that gets me the right order now, yay. My next problem i've been spinning my wheels on is to how to render the json data into appended DOM data.. anyways, here's the updated code:

Comment: So if i understand the magical line, its a listener, similar to the Model listeners, that after fetch is done on this.foodtrucks, sync is called. Our listener then triggers the render call. This is a blocking synchronous call.. correct?

Comment: No, `sync` is just a name of an events that collections or models will trigger when `synchronising` back to your data store. It has nothing to do with blocking/non-blocking thing whatsoever.

The problem you are facing though, does relate to sync/async. When you `fetch` your collection make an `ajax` request back to your server. That happen when you init your view. Now you can render on it straightaway while your collection still fetching data. This talk may help you: http://amy.palamounta.in/2013/04/12/unsuck-your-backbone/ or this blog: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/category/backbone/