# Backbone: view's model is undefined when passing it a model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Here's the entirety of my simple Backbone app. When I instantiate a new view, I'm passing it a model, but when the view calls `attributes` on the model, it says model is undefined:

```
class App.Recipe extends Backbone.Model

class App.RecipeList extends Backbone.Collection
  url: '/users/4/recipes'
  model: App.Recipe

@recipeList = new App.RecipeList
@recipeList.fetch()

class App.RecipeView extends Backbone.View
  template: _.template(@model.attributes)
  render: ->
    @$el.html(@template)
    @

@recipeView = new App.RecipeView(model: recipeList.models[0])

$ ->
  $('#featured_recipes').html(window.recipeView.render())
```

In the console, `recipeList.models[0]` returns a JSON object that does indeed have an `attributes` property. So when I instantiate the view and pass it a model, why do I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined`?

My guess is that `@model` is getting evaluated at runtime, before I pass in the model. Is there a way to defer that? Or am I wrong?

I've also tried the `_.bindAll @` in the initialize function of the view. No dice.

PS — I'm obviously a noob, so if you see other antipatterns or things I'm going to run into here, feel free to mention them.

### Edit

I've tried the answer outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826149/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-replace-of-undefined-backbone-js) of adding the template inline in my `initialize` method like this:

```
class @App.RecipeView extends Backbone.View
  tagName: 'li'
  initialize: ->
    _.bindAll @, 'render'
    template = _.template $('#featured_recipes').html()
  render: ->
    @$el.html @model.toJSON()
    @
```

But then I get `Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined` , which I know is from underscore calling template on something that isn't in the DOM yet, and that's happening because this gets called before my DOM renders. Any thoughts?

### Edit 2

Now I've moved the entire app into the footer of my `haml` layout, so that the `$(#featured-_recipes')` div is in the DOM. Then I changed the view to this:

```
class @App.RecipeView extends Backbone.View
  tagName: 'li'
  initialize: ->
    _.bindAll @, 'render'
  @template: _.template $('#featured_recipes').html()
  render: ->
    @$el.html @template(@model.toJSON())
    @
```

But I'm still getting `Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined` .

Comment: possible duplicate of [backbone.js view renders before model fetch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220092/backbone-js-view-renders-before-model-fetch)

Answer (score -1):

Try the following. I added an initialize method to your View, and I used Backbone's Collection get method to get your recipe.

```
class App.RecipeView extends Backbone.View
  initialize: (options) ->
    @model = options.recipe 

  template: _.template(@model.attributes)
  render: ->
    @$el.html(@template)
    @


@view = new App.RecipeView
          recipe: recipeList.get(0)
```

Comment: If I use `recipeList.get('c1')` (0 was the index of the model array, but `get` apparently takes an id, so `c1` worked there) in the console, it returns a model, but I updated my code to reflect yours, and even though `recipeList.get('c1')` does indeed return a model, `@model.attributes` is still undefined.

Comment: I've also confirmed that `recipeList.get('c1').attributes` is defined.

Comment: `_.template(@model.attributes)` won't work as `@` won't be the right thing in that context, `@` will be the class, not the instance.